# The binary is invalid. A symbolic link resolves to a file that doesn't exist. how to fix this on iphone

Tags: iphone, linker, linker-errors

i am getting this error while submitting app to app store

**The binary is invalid.  A symbolic link resolves to a file that doesn't exist. 
Relative location:hello.app/HMAC.3**

I have a OpenSSL folder  , now how to set the relative path so that all subfolder is linked ??

right now i am doing

"Header search path"  OpenSSL
"library search path" "$(SRCROOT)"

Comment: Inser the entire debug output. It might mean that you misspelled a header file.

Comment: see the output above , i have 15 lines like that

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a linker problem, indeed.

You are obviously linking to a framework/library.

Headers from that library are important for the compiler, so your code can compile, with all the macros/constants/typedefs/classes from those headers.¨

But that's only the compilation step. You final binary also need to be linked with the library.

Checks your project's build settings. If you need a library/framework, importing the headers is not enough. You'll also need to link with the library/framework. Build Settings->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries.

Comment: i did that link with lib ... no success :(